# The go command "go get" is giving unrecognized import path error

Tags: go

I am working on RHEL7 and trying to download dependency 
https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2

My go version is `go1.12 linux/amd64`
and go env is:

```
`GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/ash/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/ash/GoWork/src/prj"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build314905315=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"`
```

and when I try to run the command:

```
 `go get -v -u -insecure gopkg.in/yaml.v2`
```

> It gave me following error: `Fetching
>   https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1 https fetch failed: Get
>   https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1: proxyconnect tcp: read tcp
>   10.xxx.xxx.xxx:46884->10.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080: read: connection reset by peer Fetching http://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1 package
>   gopkg.in/yaml.v2: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
>   (http/https fetch: Get http://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1: proxyconnect
>   tcp: read tcp 10.xxx.xxx.xxx:46886->10.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080: read:
>   connection reset by peer)`

Also I able to run go get any package from github.com e.g. `go get github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` works just fine.
I am able to do `curl -k https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2` and this return me the html page and confirms that connection is established from my VM to gopkg.in. Can anyone please tell what I am missing. Let me know if you need more info

Comment: How long has this been going on? Could just be a temporary unavailability of gopkg.in.

Comment: Just tried `go get -u gopkg.in/yaml.v2` and it works like charm.

Comment: This looks like a problem with your proxy, not with the go tools.

Comment: @JimB this isn't proxy issue as `curl -k https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2` returns me the html page.
@Abdullah it works for me on my mac and windows but not on RHEL7.

Comment: The proxy is doing something different, because it's closing your connection: `read: connection reset by peer`. The go tool is not doing that, though it must be doing something different from what curl is doing.

Comment: @JimB you are probably right, but what is the solution.

Comment: why are you  passing the flag insecure. Did you try without it?

Comment: @JoaoHenrique yes I tried without insecure flag as well.